# Hide element when mouse leaves the element for x-amount of ms

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm struggling with creation of this observable. I have a hide-able element in my `Angular` app. When the user leaves with mouse over this element and he doesn't enters lets say in 500ms, the element should hide.

The marble diagram:

```
onleave --x-------x------------------------>
onenter -----x----------------------------->
                  <--500ms-->
_________________________________________
hide    ---------------------x------------->
```

```
const leave$ = fromEvent(this.selector.nativeElement,"mouseleave");
const enter$ = fromEvent(this.selector.nativeElement,"mouseenter");

const hide$ = // ToDo: implement logic
```

**EDIT:**

I've created an observable, but it does't work the way I would like:

```
const leave$ = fromEvent(this.backgroundSelector.nativeElement, "mouseleave");
const enter$ = fromEvent(this.backgroundSelector.nativeElement, "mouseenter");

const hide$ = leave$.pipe(
      mergeMap(event =>
          of(event).pipe(
                delay(500),
                takeUntil(enter$)
          )
      )
);

hide$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(_ => this.hideSelector());
```

The issue is, the element is hiding only when I return with mouse cursor after 500ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use debounceTime operator on mouseleave event. As [mentioned at documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime)

> DebounceTime discard emitted values that take less than the specified
>   time between output

On mouseenter event you need to discard emitted values from mouseleave event. And for this case you can simple use [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) operator, which will discard inner observable emit values.

```
const main = document.getElementById('main');
const content = document.getElementById('content');    

 fromEvent(main, 'mouseenter')
 .pipe(   
   switchMap(event => {
     content.style.display = 'block';
     return fromEvent(main, 'mouseleave').pipe(debounceTime(500));
   }))
 .subscribe(val => {
  content.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Here is example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-mouse-leave?embed=1&file=index.ts)